How to avoid E0515 error when using dynamically generated SQL queries with sqlx in Rust?
I'm developing a Rust application using sqlx with SQLite, and I'm encountering an issue with lifetime management when dynamically generating SQL queries.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
use sqlx::{sqlite::SqlitePool, query_as, FromRow};
use sqlx::Error;
use futures::stream::Stream;
use futures::StreamExt;
use std::pin::Pin;

struct Dao {
    pool: SqlitePool,
}

impl Dao {
    pub fn new(pool: SqlitePool) -> Self {
        Self { pool }
    }

    pub async fn find<'a>(&'a self, order_by: &str) -> Result<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<MyStruct, Error>> + Send + 'a>>, Error> {
        let sql = format!("SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY {}", order_by);

        // Execute query
        let stream = query_as::<_, MyStruct>(&sql)
            .fetch(&self.pool);

        // Return the stream
        Ok(Box::pin(stream))
    }
}

#[derive(FromRow, Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let pool = SqlitePool::connect("sqlite::memory:").await?;

    // Create table
    sqlx::query("CREATE TABLE my_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)")
        .execute(&pool).await?;

    // Insert sample data
    sqlx::query("INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES ('example 1')")
        .execute(&pool).await?;
    sqlx::query("INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES ('example 2')")
        .execute(&pool).await?;

    let dao = Dao::new(pool);
    let order_by = "name DESC";
    let mut stream = dao.find(order_by).await?;

    while let Some(result) = stream.next().await {
        match result {
            Ok(record) => println!("Found record: {} - {}", record.id, record.name),
            Err(e) => eprintln!("Error: {}", e),
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}

When I run this code, I encounter the following error:
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `sql`
  --> src/issues/avoid-e0515.rs:24:9
   |
20 |         let stream = query_as::<_, MyStruct>(&sql)
   |                                              ---- `sql` is borrowed here
...
24 |         Ok(Box::pin(stream))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

It seems that sqlx::query_as holds a reference to the query string, and this reference cannot outlive the function scope where the string is created.
Is there a way to safely pass a dynamically generated SQL query to sqlx::query_as without encountering lifetime issues in Rust? Or is this inherently impossible due to Rust's strict borrowing rules? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
Edit:
I have added code to create the table and insert sample records to make it easier to reproduce the issue. The problem persists and the error message remains the same.

What you are probably looking for is query with dynamic input, which allows you to define an SQL statement with placeholders and insert the values later.
The article explains how to do this in a safe manner (avoiding SQL injection), so I recommend reading the entire page carefully. The function would then look like this in your case:
pub async fn find<'a>(&'a self, order_by: &'a str) -> Result<Pin<Box<dyn Stream<Item = Result<MyStruct, Error>> + Send + 'a>>, Error> {
    // Execute query
    let stream = query_as::<_, MyStruct>("SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY $1")
        .bind(order_by)
        .fetch(&self.pool);

    // Return the stream
    Ok(Box::pin(stream))
}

Note: The documentation for query_as recommends against using SELECT * as the column ordering may differ. You should name your columns explicitly.

Thank you for your suggestion. Using placeholders allowed the code to compile, but it didn't solve the issue. The query didn't correctly apply the order by condition, and my original problem about handling the lifetime of dynamically generated SQL query strings still persists. I appreciate your help.

@SoichiroShishido Using placeholders is the correct approach. What exactly didn't work?

I tried using placeholders as suggested. The code compiles, but the ORDER BY condition doesn't seem to apply correctly. For example, with order_by = "name DESC", the query still returns "example 1" before "example 2".
So, while placeholders are a correct approach, they don't seem to work for dynamic ORDER BY clauses in this case.

@SoichiroShishido I found this question which faces the same issue. It seems like the placeholders escape the column name and keywords, so instead or odering by name in descending order, it is ordering by the literal string name DESC.

Maybe you can create your own struct that wraps the Stream object and the formatted string, and then return that struct instead. This should solve the lifetime issue since the string and the stream are destroyed at the same time and neither outlives the other

Thank you for all the suggestions and comments. After considering the feedback, I decided to use a static SQL string with a case statement to handle the dynamic ORDER BY clause. This approach avoids the issue with placeholders escaping the column name and keywords. For example: ORDER BY CASE WHEN ? = 'id' THEN id WHEN ? = 'name' THEN name ... END ASC. This way, I can dynamically order the results while avoiding the lifetime issue with dynamically generated SQL query strings. I appreciate the help and insights provided by everyone. Thank you!
